# Calculus - Prove infinity limit using esplion-delta

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\infty$$

All M>0 exists $\delta>0$ so all x with $0<|x-1|<\delta$ implies $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>M$

My proof (It probably incorrect) :

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} > M$$ 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} > M$$ 
$$1>M*(1-x)^2$$ 
$$\frac{1}{M}>(1-x)^2$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}>1-x$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}-1>1-x-1$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}-1>-x$$
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}+1<x$$

$$0<\delta \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}+1$$

But $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}+1$ could be $<0$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you are looking for large $M$ and the result must thus be wrong, since your bound on $\delta$ goes to $1-0 = 1$ for $M$ to infinity, implying that $1/(1-2)^2 = 1 > M$...

Comment: You want $|1-x|<\delta$ to imply $f(x)>M$. It's not clear what that last line did to ensure that $|1-x|<\delta$ implies $f(x)>M$.

Comment: In any event, that is not a proof, that is an attempt to derive a value $\delta$. A proof would be, once you have such a $\delta$, how would it show that if $|x-1|<\delta$ that $f(x)>M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you'd be done by noticing that $(1-x)^2 = |1-x|^2$ and thus the condition
$$f(x) > M \Leftrightarrow 1 > M(1-x)^2$$
is fulfilled if ($\Leftarrow$)
$$M \delta^2 < 1$$
or ($\Leftrightarrow$)
$$\delta < \frac1{\sqrt M}$$
so chose $\delta(M) = \begin{cases} \frac1{2\sqrt M} & M > 0 \\ 1 & M\le 0\end{cases}$ and you are done. (Note that WLOG $M>0$ is allowed so we don't have to chose a $\delta$ for $M\le 0$, but for $M\le 0$, $\delta$ can be chosen arbitrarily anyways.)

Comment: We can WLOG assume M is positive.

Comment: @DaochenWang Yep, the OP did this for us BTW. And $M \le 0$ allows arbitrary choice of $\delta$ ($\delta = \infty$ ^^)

Comment: @AlexR Thank for your help, but shouldn't it be $$0<\delta \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}$$?

Comment: @JaVaPG That's the condition imposed on $\delta$ so that we have $f(x) > M$. We need to _chose_ $\delta$ from the range $(0,\frac1{\sqrt M})$, excluding $\frac1{\sqrt M}$. $\frac1{2\sqrt M}$ is probably the most natural choice therein.

Comment: Technically, this is a backwards proof. You have to trace back to show that if $0<|1-x|<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{M}}$ then $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>M$$ That's easy to do, but it is worth remembering what we are actually trying to show.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You can save on this backtracking by noting that all transformations we did were equivalences ($\Leftrightarrow$) and not only implications ($\Rightarrow$). I have added the corresponding arrows to clarify this :)